# Yii: How change unique criteria?

Tags: php, yii

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('entity_category_id, entity_id', 'required'),
        array('preferred','boolean'),

        // unique with condition
        array('email','unique',
            'criteria'=>array(
                'condition' => 'gmail= :gmail OR email= :email',
                'params' => array(':email' => $this->email, ':gmail' => $this->email)
            ),
        ),

        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, entity_category_id, entity_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

Above unique query run WHERE clause as (gmail = 'abc' OR email= 'abc') AND (email = 'abc)
but I don't want and condition, i want only (gmail = 'abc' OR email= 'abc') in where clause

Comment: try remove unique validator ?

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi  invalid validation rule error occured

Comment: for this you need to write your own custom validator .. here is the link http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal that criteria is added to the original condition. From the [Yii API](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUniqueValidator#criteria-detail):

> **criteria:** additional query criteria. Either an array or CDbCriteria. This will be combined with the condition that checks if the attribute value exists in the corresponding table column

I think the easiest way to resolve your problem is to create your own validator in your model class:

```
public function EmailValidator($attribute,$params)
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->condition = 'gmail= :gmail OR email= :email';
    $criteria->params = array(':email' => $this->email, ':gmail' => $this->email);
    $result = $this->findAll($criteria);
    if(!empty($result)) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Email already exists!');
    }
    return;
}
```

And call it in your `rules` method:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
       //Other rules
       array('email', 'EmailValidator'),
    );
}
```